# Not sure whether to treat my data as nominal or scale

Tags: spss, categorical-data

The data I have is based on percentages. I have several variables on percent of children that have been immunized. So one column that is one kind of immunization, and is ordered by state. So for example in my data it shows that in Massachusetts, 53.3% of children have gotten the HPV4 vaccine. I want to correlate them with another column that has percent of children that have asthma by state, like in Massachusetts, 9.8% of kids have asthma. I'm not sure whether to treat the data as nominal or scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your data is definitely not nominal, and I question whether it is ordinal. It seems more continuous and has a meaningful zero. It seems more ratio, and you shouldn't limit your analysis by selecting a lower data type.

Comment: So how would I categorize the data? Right now in SPSS they are all in the scale measure, and are all numeric.

Comment: Don't categorize it. Why would you do that? It throws away data.

Comment: Peter is absolutely right, why would you lose power of analysis and make it categorical.  It is continuous, which I think SPSS calls scale.